# Can't open Properties view in ConstrainLayout editor

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-constraintlayout

I have problem with `ConstraintLayout` editor. I'm using **Android Studio 2.2** preview 4 on Linux, ConstrainLayout version 1.0.0-alpha3.

Simply, I can't open Properties view. I wonder if this is some case that I'm using Linux build, or what. **I can't find any information anywhere about that**. My friends using Mac (also preview 4) can open that view.

There are some screen shots:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Switch to the design mode and the magic will happen!

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUF0s.png)